# Kafka 1.0.0 - Serialized.with() uses default serde instead of the ones provided

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We recently updated our kafka version from 0.10 to 1.0 and I am updating the deprecated code

```
KTable<Long, myClass> myKTable = this.streamBuilder
            .stream(Serdes.Long(), mySerde, sub_topic)
            .groupByKey(Serdes.Long(), mySerde)
            .reduce(myReducer, my_store);
```

to this

```
KTable<Long, myClass> myKTable = this.streamBuilder
            .stream(sub_topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), mySerde))
            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), mySerde))
            .reduce(myReducer, Materialized.as(my_store));
```

My stream throws an error while serializing in `groupByKey`. The `Serialized.with()` does not use the `keySerde` provided and defaults back to `byteArray`. And this `byteArray serde` then encounters my key which is a `Long` and throws a cast error.

Has anyone else encountered this error in the 1.0.0 version of kafka. The first code with the outdated version of kafka works fine. But updating the code to use `Serialized.with()` does not seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the stack trace? I actually think the issue is with `reduce()` -- you need to specify the `Serdes` via `Materialized` again.

This is kinda regression on the new API and got fixed recently in `trunk`: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/4919 Thus, upcoming 2.0 release will contain the fix.